# button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open('page1.aspx?CheckedItem=" + checkedItem.ToString() + "'');"); is not working properly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

my client side code button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open('page1.aspx?CheckedItem=" + checkedItem.ToString() + "','mywindow',');"); is not executing on the first click.But it is working fine from second click onwards.I wrote this code inside the button click event.

I had tried to put this inside the page_load ,but the problem is i need to return a value from this page.
here is the code

```
protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //StringBuilder checkedItem = new StringBuilder();
    checkedItem.Length = 0;
    foreach (ListItem i in chkValidation.Items)
    {
        if (i.Selected)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(checkedItem)))
            {
                checkedItem.AppendFormat(i.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                checkedItem.AppendFormat(",");
                checkedItem.AppendFormat(i.Text);
            }
        }
        btn_Preview.Attributes.Add("onclick",
                                   "javascript:window.open('TimePhaseAttributePreview.aspx?CheckedItem=" + 
                                   checkedItem.ToString() + "','mywindow','menubar=0,resizable=0,width=350,height=250');");
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: Given your "I wrote this code inside the button click event" I will need to see the code! Got a jsfiddle? Also, don't put `javascript:` in the value of an onclick attribute.

Comment: hai MrLister,here is the code

Comment: not related to the answer. above code you are adding attribute in a loop. it shoud be outside of the loop

Comment: @MrLister why not putting javascript there?

Comment: Because it's redundant. `onclick="dosomething()"` has the same result as `onclick="javascript:dosomething()"` so you don't need the `javascript:`. The colon also makes it look (to the untrained eye) like a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the code in any page event. like page_load,init.. or use [`RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx)

Comment: thanks chamika.But the thing is i need to get the value of "checkedItem" from this page always.so cant put it in page_load

Comment: if you can't use it in the page load, you can use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OnClientClick, not OnCLick

Change your code to

```
button1.OnClientClick = "javascript:window.open('page1.aspx?CheckedItem=" + checkedItem.ToString() + "'
                        ,'mywindow',')";
```

Comment: hi shai,let me check with this one